# snow data for US

Tags: data, united-states, weather

I'm an amateur to weather. I'm trying to find a snow data set for my weather impact sales  project. I need daily snow depth and snow total for different region or states.

I found this : http://nsidc.org/data/g02158  but it said very specifically *These data are not suitable for snow fall events or totals for specific regions.*
This seems a good resource:
https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/snowmonitoring/fema/

But, they don't only have snow till Mar 2017.
Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: They probably don't have snow data after March 2017, possibly because there isn't much snow in the USA after March.

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then [opendata.se] Stack Exchange will be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The SNOTEL network measures snow depth and equivalent water content at numerous places in the US west. Check [this page](https://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/snow/) for the location of stations and the years of coverage. Note that these are point readings and do not reflect on the snow depth over a broad region or state.

Answer (score 1):

There is global snow cover data available from NASA's MODIS satellite. The data is available for download from the [MODIS](https://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/mod10.php) site. Note, it isn't a very user friendly website or dataset so might require quite a bit of processing time and knowledge to get something useful out of it.

> This data set contains daily, gridded snow cover and albedo derived
>   from radiance data acquired by the Moderate Resolution Imaging
>   Spectroradiometer (MODIS) on board the Terra satellite. Snow cover is
>   identified using the Normalized Difference Snow Index (NDSI) and a
>   series of screens designed to alleviate errors and flag uncertain snow
>   cover detections.